# Django JSON custom serializing losing datetime type

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I'm encoding data fetched from a Django cursor using Django json libraries, however I'm seeing datetimes after deserializing are now unicode type. Simple example:

```
import datetime
from django.core.serializers.json import json, DjangoJSONEncoder


today = datetime.datetime.now()
encoded = json.dumps(today, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
type(json.loads(encoded))
>> unicode
```

If I'm not mistaken variable types should be respected. Then I thought maybe there was something like a DjangoJSONDecoder, but nothing. what am I doing wrong? is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can't work how you think it should. The point is that JSON has no native type for dates/times, which is why the Django serializer converts datetimes to strings. But, of course, once they're strings, then they're strings; the deserializer has no way of knowing that they were once datetimes. You *could*, if you like, write a further custom deserializer that attempts to call `strptime` on each string, to see if it "should" be a datetime; but the overhead will be huge, and (depending on your data) could be subject to false positives.

Comment: Thanks, I thought JSON had date/time support, but checking now there's an effort to standardize on ISO 8601. Knowing this, I will tackle the problem in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify custom decoder class for `json.loads` (`cls` kwarg)

Comment: `json.loads(encoded, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)`  like this ? This raises `AttributeError: 'DjangoJSONEncoder' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @maraujop `DjangoJSONEncoder` encodes values (.dumps them), so can't be used in `.loads`. You might implement your own decoder that know what it will parse. Otherwise it would be guessing.