# How to correctly deserialize datetime objects stored in JSONField with DjangoJSONEncoder?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-jsonfield

I'm storing `datetime` objects in a `JSONField` with **Django 2.1** and a PostgreSQL, but I can't find a way to correctly deserialize them when querying database :

I've tried to use `DjangoJSONEncoder` which works correctly for serialization.
But deserialization does'nt work properly

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder)


class BookTest(TestCase):
    def test_JSONField_deserialize(self):
        # record it in PostgreSQL Database :
        instance = Book.objects.create(data=
                                       {'date': tz.now()}
                                       )
        # Retrieve it from PostgreSQL Database :
        result = Book.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        # Test the type :
        self.assertEqual(type(result.data['date']), datetime)
```

```
AssertionError: <class 'str'> != <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Do I need to extends `DjangoJSONEncoder`, or provide a `.from_db_value()` custom method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054440/django-json-custom-serializing-losing-datetime-type) answer well the question.

By serializing into JSON, the dates/times format is loosed, and build a `decoder` would structurally mean accepting the risk of false positive.